# How to create a new, unique RMI registry on some free port?

Tags: java, jenkins-plugins, rmi

### Situation

I'm writing a Jenkins build step plugin, and want my other processes on localhost to call my plugin's main process' functions and give it data objects.

For this, I decided to use RMI, therefore I want to create an RMI registry, so the other processes can call my functions:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/rmi/registry/LocateRegistry.html

I want the registry to take any free port available on the system. Usually this is done by providing a port of 0 to the registry/socket creation.

However, an RMI registry maintains an ID, preventing a subsequent creation if a registry of that ID already exists on the JVM. With a port of 0, that registry's ID is 0.

### Question

There are other actors on the same JVM instance (plugins), that may have created or may want to create a RMI registry on port 0 for port discovery. This prevents me from creating my own registry with a free port. This is my problem, because I don't want to collide with other registries on this JVM, yet still get an available free port.

Is there some solution for this?

Did I get something wrong?

### Things I rejected

- If I used an existing registry, I'd be concerned that my bindings will collide with existing bindings.
- I tried to provide a custom  `RMIServerSocketFactory` implementation to `LocateRegistry.createRegistry`, choosing a free port (port = 0), and calling `createRegistry` itself with any other port for id. However, the created Registry somehow uses the correct port, but internally thinks it uses the given port. I am concerned, this will lead to further problems later on. Also, I cannot reliable choose a nonexisting id, as I'd have to try several if they turn out to be used already. This is the same problem I set out to solve with the ports.
- Poking a port with a socket connection, then creating a Registry on that port does not work for me. Because this introduces a gap between forfeiting the port and creating the registry on that port. And I don't want another process to jump in and take the port in the mean time.

Comment: 1. I always use the full package/classname of the remote interface as the bind-name. That way there is realistically no chance of a name collision.

Comment: 2. You will have to explain what exactly you mean by 'however, the created Registry somehow uses the correct port, but internally thinks it uses the given port.' This has no apparent meaning.

Comment: 3. But specifying `new ServerSocket(0)` in your `RMISocketFactory` automatically gives you a free port. At that point all guesswork is over. All you then have to do is interrogate its local port, and store that somewhere where the clients can find it, and then return that socket to the caller. Which leaves open the question of how you *are* going to communicate it to the clients.

Comment: @user207421 1. That's a very good recommendation, thank you! We also had problems declaring message-relevent custom definitions (like return types) to an existing RMI server, when that server was on a different JVM. Therefore we did not proceed in that direction.

Comment: @user207421 2. The created registry remembers the port argument given to it twofold: As an ID, and as a port variable of some sort. However, when we choose a different actual port (by means of our own RMISocketFactory), then the created registry actually uses that different port, but internally has a cache of the given argument port as ID and as port variable. An inconsistency whose repercussions I cannot grasp.

Comment: @user207421 3. You're right about the `RMISocketFactory`; and communication to the client is taken care of, thank you. This third point wanted to rule out the thought of using a separate socket in order to determine a free port; and the separate socket would then have to be closed in order for the RMISocketFactory's Socket to open it. As I said, we ruled it out.

Comment: I still don't know what you mean by 'as an ID', or 'cache of the given argument'. Please explain. But I would just use port 1099 as God intended, and if there's one already running use it, and regard it as a gift from God. Otherwise you're left with the problem of telling the clients what the port is, and it is exactly this kind of bootstrap problem that the Regsitry was designed to solve in the first place.

Comment: @user207421 Two subsequent calls of `LocateRegistry.createRegistry(0)` yield `java.rmi.server.ExportException: internal error: ObjID already in use`. That's the ID I meant.

The registry internally maintains an TCPEndpoint object, which has a "listenport" and a "port". That's the port cache I meant. The TCPEndpoint does not reflect the port that my RMISocketFactory chooses, but the argument that is entered into `createRegistry`.

Comment: That ID is the Registry's Object ID. It has nothing to do with the port number. You can only export one Registry on each port from a single JVM. In earlier JVMs, don't ask me how early, you could only export one Registry per JVM regardless of port.

Comment: Exactly. But because of this, you cannot count on createRegistry(0) to actually give you a registry on a free port, because if someone other had the same idea, these two registries block each other.

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing what I found out in the mean time, RMI is not a good fit for the scenario I want to cover.

Java's RMI mechanism is designed for:

- sharing a Registry at the default port of 1099
- sharing a Registry at a specific port that you provide beforehand

In both cases these problems apply:

- If the port is already in use then creating the Registry fails, leaving open what to do about it.
- Reusing an RMI registry that you do not control yourself brings about the possibility that the registry goes down mid-communication (because its process can go down for any valid reason).
- "Look if the default Registry exists, if not create it" is a bad pattern, if your process is short-lived. Other processes will bind to your created Registry, which then goes down with the process.
- All server instances on the same Registry need to use a binding that hopefully does not collide.
- If there are several similar server/client processes that use the same implementation (for example parallel jobs), and therefore the same binding names, they need to sort out their individual communication through unique binding names.

The RMI mechanism is not designed for creating an ad-hoc RMI registry that is dedicated to a single server/client communication:

- Creating an RMI registry on a random free port (by providing port=0) works only on the very first call within this JVM process. Any further attempts at creating another RMI registry on another random free port fails.
- Creating an RMI registry on a random free port (by custom RMISocketFactory) leads to inconsistent internal state. Also, you need to sort out which ID to give the Registry up front, which defeats the purpose of using an RMI registry in the first place.
- An RMI registry cannot be closed. It stays online as long as the process's JVM stays.

Therefore, in a plugin scenario, where, within the same JVM, other actors may execute code, and you need to start several communications to very similar spawned processes, and there may be other processes around, that do the same thing, RMI opens several points of failure that cannot easily be mitigated.